# Configuration option like 'git -w'

Tags: git, whitespace

I almost always use 'git -w' when viewing diffs or blames. Can I make that the default behavior with a configuration option?

Comment: @JcKelley You are probably right. Although in this particular case your answer does not exactly solve my problem, it seems to be the closest one can get...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git config does not *directly* support that kind of thing. Your best bet is to make a `git alias` in your configuration file:

```
[alias]
diffw = diff -w
```

or use the git config alias command:

```
$ git config --global alias.diffw 'diff -w'
```

I would read up on the [Git Config Docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to master this further.

***EDIT*** Remember that you cannot overwrite traditional git commands, so you will have to use `diffw` or something, you cannot hard overwrite `diff`